# Laravel 5 Querying Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Here is the relationship 1 code:

```
/**
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\IPAddress', 'group_id');
}
```

and relationship 2 code:

```
/**
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\IPGroups');
}
```

> I want to get all ip addresses that belongs to specified group. I don't want to write raw queries, I need to be done with querying relationship. Does anyone has an idea?

I tried to do something like this:

```
 /**
 * Get IP Addresses of specified group
 * @param Request $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIP(Request $request)
{
    $group = IPGroups::findOrFail($request->group_id);
    return $group->address;
}
```

> but I need to add one where statement where I can pick only active ip addresses.

Here is the model 1 code:

```
    namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class IPGroups extends Model
{
    /**
     * Working Table
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'ip_groups';

    /**
     * Guarded Values From Mass Assignment
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [ 'id' ];

    /**
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\IPAddress', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

and the second model code:

```
    namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class IPAddress extends Model
{
    /**
     * Working Table
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'ips';

    /**
     * Protected Values From Mass Assignment
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [ 'group_id', 'ip', 'description', 'status' ];

    /**
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\IPGroups');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - How to use where conditions for relation's column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885127/laravel-4-how-to-use-where-conditions-for-relations-column)

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting all ip addresses, I want just active ones. In database table I have column status['Active', 'Deleted'].

Comment: did you try chaining a where clause after findOrFail?

Comment: `->where('columnName', 'Active');`

Comment: What models do those relations belong to?

Comment: @Adamnick , I have already tried but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why does not work? Any error? Or just ignoring the `where`?

Comment: it's ignoring the where clause... like you see, I first fetch the group and then I fetch ip addresses that belongs to specified group... I just need to query those ip addresses. I need only active addresses.

Comment: What about adding return $group->address->where('status','Active'); ? I mean, cast the `where` in the addresses, not the group.

Comment: I have tried with return $group->address->where('status','=','Active') and it returns me the empty array. Now I will tried yours.

Comment: @Amarnasan it works... Thank you man... I was trying like $group->address->where('status','=','Active') but it doesn't work but $group->address->where('status','Active') works fine for me!

Comment: @HerilMuratovic Cool! Now you can accept my answer! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, getting only the addresses with status as 'Active':

```
return $group->address->where('status','Active');
```

The reason this doesn't work:

```
return $group->address->where('status','=','Active');
```

is that the `where` we are using here is the `where` of the class `Collection`, which doesn't accept a comparator as second parameter as the `where` of the `Model`s do.