# Laravel searching many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a many to many relation between a Books table and a Authors table. The pivot table (author_book) contains the the author_id and the book_id.

I want my users to be able to search trough the database using a simple search form. Whenever a user enters a keyword i want to search fields in both tables.

What i need is something like this...

`return View::make('result')->with('books', Book::with('authors')
            ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('**authors->table->name**', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get());`

I need a way to also search the authors table and check is the keyword maches the author name.

The relation is set up in both my author and book model.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634398/eloquent-calling-where-on-a-relation/18634716#18634716 - it's also about adding a where on a relation.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work for me because i need to use the $keyword variable inside of the function.

Comment: @303K you can pass parameters, such as your `$keyword`, into a closure with the [`use` language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be ideal solution but for complex queries like this I find it easier to simply use raw SQL queries.

Something like this in this case:

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * 
                              FROM books 
                              INNER JOIN authors 
                              WHERE books.title LIKE '%$keyword%'
                              OR authors.name LIKE '%$keyword%' "));
```